# Regression for data over the course of two years

Tags: regression, growth-model

I have a quick question regarding an analysis that I am doing.  I am looking at metrics for years 2013 and 2014. What I want to do is a build a growth model using growth rates.

Suppose that I have a growth variable that I am trying to predict which is defined as Y% = (Y2014 - Y2013)/(Y2013) and two other independent variables, X1% and X2%, which are growth variables as well. In addition to this I also have a factor variable so my model is the following Y% ~ X1% + X2% + Factor.

I want to run this regression in R, but I wanted to make sure that my model is adequate. Is there anything I should be careful about? Are there any other ways to go about this? The question I am trying to answer is "Does growth in one variable(%X1, %X2) lead to growth in the my dependent variable(%Y).

I am not looking carry out a super formal analysis or anything like that. I just came on here to make sure that I am on the right path.

Comment: So far so good. But there are a million things you should check to make sure you model is adequate. These would take a long time to list. The simplest indication of some problem in the model is that you can see a clear (or less clear) pattern in model residuals. Hence you should plot your residuals once you have run the regression. If there are no patterns there, you can relax a bit  (although formal testing for different kinds of patterns would still help). If you do find a pattern, you should think how harmful it could be, why it is there and how you could account for it in the model.

Comment: By *how harmful* I mean that certain patterns may indicate certain problems with your estimates of regression coefficients. E.g. heteroshedastic residuals indicate inefficient estimation of model coefficients.